# How to remove the space between context menu items in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have items in context menu, there is more space between the items. i tried in so many ways like creating item container, reducing margin to 0 and padding to zero. Nothing works.May Any one help me to sort out the problem.

```
  <Style TargetType="local:ContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ContextMenu">                    
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <ListView x:Name="PART_ContextMenuListView" BorderThickness="0"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"                           
                              Background="White" >                           
                    </ListView>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>        
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                        
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>                                
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" To="NoSelectionHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                    <!--<SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>-->
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                    <!--<SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>-->
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>-->
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>-->
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>-->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                    <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                    <!--<FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>-->
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                    <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <!--<FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>-->
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent" Margin="0">
                        <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                        <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="0" Margin="0" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
                            <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent" Margin="0">
                                <!--<Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="-5" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" Margin="-5" StrokeThickness="2"/>-->
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige" Margin="-5">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                                <!--<Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Height="40" Opacity="0" Width="40">
                                        <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                        <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>-->
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#D5E1F2"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#D5E1F2"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="#D5E1F2"/>
```

And in Code Behind

```
    var cuticon = resources["CutIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var copyicon = resources["CopyIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pasteoptionsicon = resources["PasteOptionsIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pasteallicon = resources["PasteAllIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pastevalueicon = resources["PasteValueIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pasteformulaicon = resources["PasteFormulaIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pasteformaticon = resources["PasteFormatIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var pastevalueformaticon = resources["PasteValueFormatIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var insertcommenticon = resources["InsertCommentIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var editcommenticon = resources["EditCommentIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var deletecommenticon = resources["DeleteCommentIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var hyperlinkicon = resources["HyperlinkIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var removehyperlinkicon = resources["RemoveHyperlinkIcon"] as ImageSource;
        var formatcellsicon = resources["FormatCellsIcon"] as ImageSource;

        var ribbonbuttonstyle = new Style(typeof(SfRibbonButton));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.WidthProperty, "220"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.HeightProperty, "30"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.FontFamilyProperty, "Caliber"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.BackgroundProperty, "Transparent"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.SizeModeProperty, "Large"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.FontWeightProperty, "Normal"));
        ribbonbuttonstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(SfRibbonButton.MarginProperty, "0"));

        var cutbutton = new SfRibbonButton
        {
            Command = this.Commands.Cut,
            Name = "CutButton",
            Label = GridResourceWrapper.Cut,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Icon = cuticon,
        };
        cutbutton.Height = 30;
        var copybutton = new SfRibbonButton
        {
            Command = this.Commands.Copy,
            Name = "CopyButton",
            Label = GridResourceWrapper.Copy,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Icon = copyicon,
            Style = ribbonbuttonstyle,
        };
        var pasteoptionstitlebutton = new SfRibbonButton
        {
            Name = "PasteOptionsTitleButton",
            Label = GridResourceWrapper.Context_PasteOptions,
            Height = 26,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
            Icon = pasteoptionsicon,
            Style = ribbonbuttonstyle,
            FontWeight = Windows.UI.Text.FontWeights.Bold,
            IsHitTestVisible = false,
            //Padding = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 2)
        };
```

Comment: Please, provide also XAML of SampleContextMenu element

Answer (score 0):

You have not provide any code, but you can create your custom flyout as context menu. [This GitHub sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlContextMenu/cs) can help you. If shortly, you can add to page resources flyout and change style as you like:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key="SampleContextMenu">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open" Tag="&#xE1A5;"  />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Print" Tag="&#xE2F6;"   />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Tag="&#xE10A;"  />
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Other">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Sort by" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Name" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Date" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Size" />
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

And inside CS:

```
        protected override void OnRightTapped(RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowContextMenu(null, e.GetPosition(null));
        e.Handled = true;

        base.OnRightTapped(e);
    }

    private void ShowContextMenu(UIElement target, Point offset)
    {
        var MyFlyout = this.Resources["SampleContextMenu"] as MenuFlyout;
        MyFlyout.ShowAt(target, offset);
    }
```

Comment: i have added the code. i need to reduce the spacing between the items

Comment: Currently in your ListViewItemStyle1 template I can see some Margin and Height attributes. But if you change them may be your control will be looking ugly. I recommend you better to open your template in Blend. In this case you will see all changes

Comment: i have removed the spacing but another issue is while mouse hover on the items, the entire range is not highlighted only certain range's background is changed

Comment: That is what I have mean whan have write about control might be looking ugly (